# Getting more info about showAlert

Tags: javascript

I run into some tutorial video, but the problem is they dont explain what thus the function do, can I ask about this code or can explain what thus the code thus

```
function showAlert(message, className) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = `alert alert-${className}`;
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");
    const main = document.querySelector(".main");
    container.insertBefore(div, main);

    setTimeout(() => document.querySelector(".alert").remove(), 3000);

}
```

Im still learning JavaScript, thank you

Comment: It creates a div element with the alert class, adds it to the container in front of main and then removes the alert class after 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds).

Comment: better way :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/showModal